# Error building couchbase: fatal error cbsasl/cbsasl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: couchbase

Following the instructions in https://github.com/membase/manifest I obtain the error:

```
daemon/memcached.h:12:27: fatal error: cbsasl/cbsasl.h: No such file or directory
```

after:

```
$ repo init -u git://github.com/membase/manifest.git -m branch-2.1.0.xml
$ repo sync
$ make
```

Also in branch-2.0.1.xml

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not compiling support for Ubuntu 13.10